# Trying to get json data from api and then post in site Angular 6

Tags: php, json, angular6

I am using [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) Upload API and I am creating an app to upload photos and then add them to my localhost site. I keep getting back console error:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.push../node_modules/@angular/http/fesm5/http.js.Body.json
```

If anyone can find an error in my code and point me in the right direction, I would certainly appreciate it. The component ts code is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { GalleryComponent } from '../gallery/gallery.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fileuploader',
  templateUrl: './fileuploader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fileuploader.component.css']
})
export class FileuploaderComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {}

  @Input()
    gallery: GalleryComponent;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  uploadFile(event) {
    let elem = event.target;
    if(elem.files.length > 0) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', elem.files[0]);

      this.http.post('http://localhost/angular-php/script.php', formData).subscribe((data) => {

        let jsonResponse = data.json();

        this.gallery.gotSomeDataFromTheBackend(jsonResponse.file);
        console.log('Got some data from the backend ', data);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error! ', error);
      });

    }
  }
}
```

and the PHP is:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
define(PUBLIC_KEY, 'cfcc5bbc8eb856a7d808');

$tempPath = $_FILES['file']['temp_name'];
$actualName = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$actualPath = dirname(_FILE_)."/temp/".$actualName;
move_uploaded_file($tempPath, $actualPath);


$ch = curl_init();

$post = [
  'UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY'=>PUBLIC_KEY,
  'UPLOADCARE_STORE'=>1,
  'file'=> curl_file_create($actualPath)
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo ($response);
```

Placing console.log(data); before let json..., I get:

```
Response {_body: "<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant …ngular-php\script.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />↵", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}

headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}

ok
:
true

status
:
200

statusText
:
"OK"

type
:
2

url
:
"http://localhost/angular-php/script.php"

_body
:
"<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant PUBLIC_KEY - assumed 'PUBLIC_KEY' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-php\script.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />↵<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: temp_name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-php\script.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />↵<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant _FILE_ - assumed '_FILE_' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-php\script.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />↵"

__proto__
:
Body
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(data);` if you put it before `let jsonResponse = data.json();`?

Comment: I've added the response to the console.log in the latest edit. Thank you for helping @DiabolicWords

Comment: Try this one print in console.log("data",JSON.parse(data)):

Remove that line once data.json();.

Comment: Tell me what you got while using json.parse method

Comment: Your PHP endpoint returns a document with a bunch of PHP warnings. This is not parseable JSON document :) So, my bet is that everything will work when you either remove those warning at all for the script, or modify your PHP code so no warnings or notices are raised.